# Eclipse: 'Referenced Libraries' vs 'Project and External Dependencies'

Tags: eclipse, gradle

What makes a library go in 'Referenced Libraries' vs 'Project and External Dependencies'? My gradle dependencies used to go in the latter, now they suddenly go in the former instaed and I don't understand why.

EDIT : yes, I tried refreshing, Refresh Gradle prodject, gradle eclipse, etc. It doesn't work. When I copy my code (just the classes and the build.gradle) to another computer with the same Eclipse version in another Spring Boot project, it works correctly and the gradle dependencies go in Referenced Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first is the result of the `gradle eclipse` task, which writes the downloaded jars with their locations into the project's `.classpath` file, and the latter is instead a layer of indirection where the Eclipse Buildship plug-in analyzes the `gradle.build` to provide that information programmatically and dynamically to the project's Java Build Path.